# How to name Fragment tags

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've discovered that I can make my Android application much more performant by using tags. This is great, however, I cannot find any documentation on what an Android fragment tag should look like.

I could imagine any number of ways:

```
String tag = "MyClass";
String tag = myFragment.toString();
```

Etc...

Is there a standard or method which has been accepted and documented, or are we left to our own devices to try and develop tags?

Comment: as far as I know there is no standard, they are only used by you so do whatever makes sense so you can refer to them again later.

Comment: Yeah that is what I have figured, not sure how constructive my question is.

Comment: `String` Tag = `"myMegaCoolFragTag"`. You are welcome.

Comment: What about... `String tag = "frg_MyFragment";`.